# mysql service start couldn't start what shoud I do?

Tags: mysql

after stop then remove and install it, when I finally start the service can't start
[image]

Comment: Hello, can you check if is there another port used by another server? you can use this command to check for mysql port: **netstat -an |find "3306"** also can you run "dir" command in the same >bin location to see if you run the same mysql service ?

Comment: Look at the Windows Event Log, in there you will likely see errors from MySQL. If they are not obvious add them to your question so we can see also

Comment: Why did you not copy/paste the TEXT? an image is sooooo useless....